# How to match a whole string if certain conditions are met

Tags: regex

Im working a lot with trying to isolate sizes from strings, however i have come into some issues.

**Current**:

https://regex101.com/r/zbEtOU/1

**Current regex**

`^([a-z]+\d*(?:\s*-\s*[a-z\d]+[/-][a-z\d]+)?|\d+)`

**Examples:**

30/32

Fixed 8 (32-36)

XS/S

m/l

1-2Y

s/m

0-3M

32

**Desired result:**

I want to isolate the first value from, but when i encounter parentheses i want to match on those values.

So actual desired outcome from the examples:

*30*/32 = **30**

Fixed 8 (*32*-36) = **32**

*XS*/S = **XS**

*m*/l = **m**

*1-2Y* = **1-2Y** (im guessing there is no way to output "1Y" in this case? Else it would overlap with 1-2M causing confusion as 1 != 1 in this case. When this happens I would prefer to get the original string) *ideal case* = **1Y**

*s*/m = **s**

*1-3M* = **1-3M** (im guessing there is no way to output "1M" in this case? Else it would overlap with 1-2Y causing confusion as 1 != 1 in this case. When this happens I would prefer to get the original string)
*ideal case* = **1M**

*32* = **32**

I'm really out of my bounds on solving this as there is a lot of different conditions here!
All regex is run insensitive, so no need to worry about capital letters.

Anyone got a nice and easy way to solve my issue??

**Everything needs to be captured in Group 1 - else my system cant isolate it**

Run in Python 3.7

Comment: Why is `1-2Y => 1Y` and `1-3M => 1M`?

Comment: There are ways to get all the values, for example with different capture groups. What is the tool or language? See for example `\((\d+)[^()]*\)|([^\s\/]+)[\/]|^(\d+)$|(\d+)-\d+([A-Z])` https://regex101.com/r/pTcObM/1

Comment: 1-3Y means 1-3 Years, while 1-3M means 1-3 Months...

Comment: Ideally i would want to grab all the values in Group 1, as my system has no idea about further groups (generic loader, so wouldnt know where to put extra groups)

Comment: Try `(?:^|.*\()(\d+(?:-\d+[A-Za-z]{1,3})?|[A-Za-z]{1,3})\b`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LPuC1X/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
(?:^|.*\()(\d+(?:-\d+[A-Za-z]{1,3})?|[A-Za-z]{1,3})\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LPuC1X/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:^|.*\()` - start of string or any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then a `(` char
- `(\d+(?:-\d+[A-Za-z]{1,3})?|[A-Za-z]{1,3})` - Group 1:

  - `\d+(?:-\d+[A-Za-z]{1,3})?` - one or more digits, followed with an optional occurrence of a `-`, one or more digits, and then one to three ASCII letters
  - `|` - or
  - `[A-Za-z]{1,3}` - one, two or three ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.